# Pyglet can't load .wav file

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pyglet

#### Env:

Ubuntu 18.04
Python 3.6.6
pyglet 1.3.2

#### Issue:

Based on [documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/media.html#loading-media) of pyglet I try to run following code:

```
import pyglet
pyglet.options["audio"] = ("openal", "pulse", "directsound", "silent")
explosion = pyglet.media.load('explosion.wav')
```

But following exceptions occured:
1) if file was converted by `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.wav`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path_to_dir>/test_sound.py", line 3, in <module>
    explosion = pyglet.media.load('zxc.wav', streaming=False)
  File "<path_to_env>lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/loader.py", line 63, in load
    source = get_source_loader().load(filename, file)
  File "<path_to_env>lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/loader.py", line 84, in load
    return WaveSource(filename, file)
  File "<path_to_env>lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/riff.py", line 197, in __init__
    raise WAVEFormatException('Not a WAVE file')
pyglet.media.sources.riff.WAVEFormatException: Not a WAVE file
```

2) or this for several .wav from internet

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path_to_dir>//test_sound.py", line 3, in <module>
    explosion = pyglet.media.load('explosion.wav', streaming=False)
  File "<path_to_env>lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/loader.py", line 63, in load
    source = get_source_loader().load(filename, file)
  File "<path_to_env>lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/loader.py", line 84, in load
    return WaveSource(filename, file)
  File "<path_to_env>lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/riff.py", line 192, in __init__
    format = wave_form.get_format_chunk()
  File "<path_to_env>lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/riff.py", line 172, in get_format_chunk
    for chunk in self.get_chunks():
  File "<path_to_env>lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/riff.py", line 108, in get_chunks
    chunk = cls(self.file, name, length, offset)
  File "<path_to_env>lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/riff.py", line 153, in __init__
    raise RIFFFormatException('Size of format chunk is incorrect.')
pyglet.media.sources.riff.RIFFFormatException: Size of format chunk is incorrect.
```

#### Question:

How to run `.wav` files via pyglet correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Like in the example, it is probably either an issue with openal or the wav-files. Are the procedural sounds playing correctly, e.g.:

```
from pyglet.media.sources.procedural import Sine
sine = Sine(duration=1, frequency=500,
                    sample_size=16, sample_rate=44100)
pyglet.media.StaticSource(sine).play()
```

and can you share an offending wav-file? I just ran a test on Linux Mint 19, Python 3.7.1 and pyglet 1.3.2 with https://github.com/pyreiz/pyreiz/blob/master/reiz/media/wav/ding.wav and it runs fine.

Comment: Ah, you might also want to check the sampling rate and bit rate of your file.

Comment: Point is - I dont want to setup AV. In last origin branch pyglet contains changed module for playing `.wav`, but they don't release it even in beta yet.